# Unknown command name and packet magic for bitcoin packets at the start of blockchain transactions

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, wallet

Recently I captured a part of blockchain when my bitcoin wallet started to syncing for the first time. I analyze about 10 Gb of traffic which was for primary transactions of bitcoin.
wireshark can detect them as bitcoin traffic but these packets don't have a valid command name and a valid packet magic. according to this link:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Network_address

all magic values are 0xD9B4BEF9, 0xDAB5BFFA, 0x0709110B and 0xFEB4BEF9.

my first question is why a lot of packets at the start of blockchain don't have a valid magic packet and valid command name, and how wireshark can detect these packets as bitcoin while they don't have a valid header?

Comment: It may be useful to show exactly what you are seeing instead of only what you're expecting to see.

Comment: @PieterWuille there a lot of incorrect values, for example for a packet i see 
"0x45022056d20ede6d23d563b5" as it's command name which isn't a valid printable value and 0x008b4830 for it's packet magic.

Comment: Presumably you're incorrectly splitting data into packets. Can you post the full data you see for a representative selections of packets? Preferably subsequent ones?

Comment: I just copy these values from wireshark. they have large size so i can't post full data here. wireshark detect them as bitcoin protocol but shows them as black packets.

Comment: If you're not showing what you're seeing, there is no way anyone can guess. I'm sure there are some small packets among them, or if not, there are paste sites where you can easily put a few MB.

Comment: as an example, start of one of these packets is shown below:

`082d2026eda71ec445dbf97b346cb65692e23b712a11fc500220174bbfea9f0c591c9efb91ee004386ad22d13eb04d748df3f1957b3a3c69b18401210294c3fba7a78fcfaae34a7154e53b03ee1d78fa87499eefdb631c84e9cfd85614feffffff02e8166500000000001976a914d6c094481a567c316af56676c4df77d23ecf3a3088ac18c00900000000001976a914808b475d6a12476fb854e8aa6dd6e85aa217c1ae88ace6c106000100000001024db340a993dadcfa7b4f4d350057e38efa0339f58dc52c4cecb027a42ff7f300000`

as wireshark's info, packet magic = 0x082d2026 and payload length is 92e23b71 which is equal to 1899750034.

Comment: @PieterWuille  do you have any opinion?